# Prestashop Edit Meta-Tag in Home Page

Tags: php, html, mysql, meta-tags, prestashop-1.5

How do change a meta tag in Prestashop ver 1.5+

```
    <meta name="description" content="Shop powered by PrestaShop" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="shop, prestashop" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en-es-fr" />
    <meta name="generator" content="PrestaShop" />
```

I need to do a verification for a website and they ask for a meta tag in the home page and it has to be exactly like this:

```
    <meta name="WEB-Verification" content="50d072ae-175c-4cbf-50d072ae-175c-4cbf" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="shop, prestashop" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en-es-fr" />
    <meta name="generator" content="PrestaShop" />
```

Can someone help me and point me in the right direction?

If i do it from mysql , in the meta_lang I can't change the name="description"

I can change the value of content="abcdefghijklm", but the value of the name="description" I can't change it.

I would appreciate a reply from you guys.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in Prefences -> SEO & URLS -> click edit beside "index"

there you go :)

Answer (score 0):

you can add it in header.tpl in your themes

Answer (score 0):

you can also use modules for this purpose like this [meta tags](http://addons.prestashop.com/en/administration-tools-prestashop-modules/17501-meta-import.html) editor